# On the Strapi Dashboard, when viewing an entry is there a way to hide the 'Created by' and 'Last update by' details?

Tags: strapi

Is it possible to hide the 'Last update By' and 'Created by' fields in the information box [in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1Vdu.png)?
Tried adding `"options": { "draftAndPublish": true, "privateAttributes": ["createdBy", "updatedBy", "created_by", "updated_by"] }` to the schema.json file for the specific collection I'm trying to remove these fields from.